# Authenticated user is always null when authentication is not required

Tags: java, spring-security

I have these mappings defined in my controller as follows:

```
@RequestMapping("/getUser1")
@ResponseBody
public String getUser1(Principal principal) {
     return principal == null ? "Not Logged In" : principal.getName();
}

@RequestMapping("/getUser2")
@ResponseBody
public String getUser2(Principal principal) {
     return principal.getName();
}
```

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is set up:

```
http.antMatcher("/**")
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/getUser1")
            .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()  // Including "/getUser2"
        .authenticated();
```

The user is authenticated so the Principal object is set in the Spring framework..

When going to /getUser2, principal is the authenticated user as expected. When going to /getUser1, principal is always null whether they are authenticated or not.

I need the get the authenticated user in the getUser1 method.

I even tried the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/getUser1")
@ResponseBody
public String getUser1() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return auth == null ? "Not Logged In" : auth.getName();
}
```

`auth` is also always null.